# In triangle ABC, ∠ACB = 60. AD and BE are angle bisectors. Prove AE + BD = AB.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Here is a diagram if it will be helpful:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that for the past two hours i have no clue.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas He at least drew a picture. The "What have you tried so far?" brigade needs to take it easy sometimes.

Comment: Perhaps bisect $\angle ACB$ and see if inspiration strikes...

Comment: @KimJongUn, go back to North Korea. :P

Comment: Seriously, is there something obvious i am not seeing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Pick $G$ on $AB$ such that $AG=AE$. It follows that the angles $\angle AFG$ and $\angle AFE$ are equal. They are labelled $\alpha$ in the figure. Other angles $\beta$ and $\mu$ are also labelled. Now, $\angle ACB=60$ implies that $\alpha+\beta=120$: 
$$
\alpha+\beta=180-(\angle FAB+\angle FBA)=180-\frac{1}{2}(\angle CAB+\angle CBA)=180-\frac{1}{2}(180-60).
$$
But we also have $2\alpha+\beta=180$ and so $\alpha=\beta=\mu=60$. The triangles $\bigtriangleup GBF$ and $ \bigtriangleup DBF$ are congruent and the result follows.

Comment: Why does such $G$ exist?

Comment: Why is α+β=120?

Comment: @АлександърГьорев I added a few details.

Comment: Just a clarification, did you mean α+β=180−(∠FAB+∠FBA) and not α+β=180−(∠FAC+∠FBA)?

Comment: @АлександърГьорев You are right, i fixed. :)

Comment: @Fermat Here's alternative way to think about $G$: $\angle AFB=120$ so if you drop a bisector from $F$ to $AB$, the intersection is in the interior of $AB$. Call that $G$.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to express everything in terms of the triangle sides and then obtain something trivial (or at least easy-to-prove).

For this, just use the property that the angle bisector divides the opposite side in the ratio of the neighbour sides i.e. $\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{AB}{BC}$.
Then (with the usual notations for triangle sides) you get
$AE=\frac{bc}{a+c}$ and $BD=\frac{ac}{b+c}$ and so we need to prove
$c=\frac{bc}{a+c}+\frac{ac}{b+c}$
which is (after expanding) equivalent to $a^2-ab+b^2=c^2$.
But this is just the Law of Cosines using $\gamma=60^\circ$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However is this the only way to solve this problem, as it is from a 7th grade textbook and frankly none of the theorems used by you are taught at that grade.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев Please see if my approach is more suited to your context.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев: To show appreciation hover the mouse below the contributor arrows and click.